I unlocked Hyper Whiteout, but I can't see the unlock in the Unlocks list? Am I just unobservant?
I got the items to unlock the Stage, double-checked on the Wiki:

 20 Orologions

I assume being unable to see the unlock conditions of Bonus Stages even after they're done, is normal, to make them extra secret?

It might be part of the Unlocks that are only shown after getting the Yellow Sign, because the similarly hidden (Hyper) Laborratory unlock from getting multiple of a different item, is the only way to get the Metaglios and Rings before getting the Yellow Sign.
